# Turbolinks partial replacement vs. Shopify Turbograft

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, turbolinks

I was recently excited about Turbolinks 3 and Partial replacement due to Nate Berkopec talk and sample todo app code. It got me excited to think that we might not have to add to the development overhead with a full blown SPA.

However, I've just learned that Turbolinks 5 will not have this feature. Would it be safe to say, Turbolinks Classic with the partial replacement is a viable way to proceed?  Or would using something like Turbograft from Shopify better serve us now in and in the future?